# How to copy a file from a remote repository?

Tags: python, git

I am writing a Python program that returns the name of all files under a given commit hash. However, what I now want to do is copy all of these files into a temporary folder. My first instinct was to take the file names and url of the remote directory. This looked something like:

```
remote_url = 'https://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + remote_dir
remote_file = str(subprocess.check_output('git fetch origin ' + str(commit_hash), shell=True))
original = remote_url + "/" + remote_file
target = "./" + local_dir + "/temp_folder"
shutil.copyfile(original, target)
```

However, I get [Errno 2] No such file or directory in this case.

Is there a way for me to copy all of the files under a given commit hash into a temporary folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [`GitPython`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) is interesting for you which allows interaction with git in python.

Comment: shutil is for file on local system. You should use http.client to get the file contents.

Comment: Depending on the hosting services, they may provide REST APIs including downloading specific files of a revision. If your hosting service does not have such APIs, you can fetch the revision first, and then extract the files from Git database. Some servers may also allow `git archive --remote=<url>`, so that you could directly run it to download the contents.